# Neo4j 2.0: advanced queries on label-based indexes possible?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

Neo4j's legacy indexes offer functionality like doing Lucene queries on them, or indexing arbitrary key/value pairs.

For example, if my `User` node looks like this: `(me { FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe'})`, I can put this user in a legacy index with a key of `FullName`, a value of `'john doe'`, and I can get this user and other users whose name starts with a 'j' with this Cypher query:

```
start withj=node:User("FullName:j*") return withj;
```

I'm thinking of converting my legacy index based application to Neo4j 2.0's label based indexes. Do these new indexes also offer this functionality or only searches on exact matches? Should I stick to legacy indexes for this kind of queries, or are there alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: No they don't yet, this will be supported in a future version, which will probably just push certain expressions of your where clause down to the index providers.

Comment: If the index isn't solely for speed, you could use the Regular Expression operator (=~) in a WHERE clause for case-insensitive match.  Ex: WHERE withj.FullName =~ "(?i)j.*"

Comment: @MichaelHunger, any idea when regex searches on labels will use the index? Is it already on the release plan, or is there a github issue that can follow?

Comment: Full text indexing will arrive, it's just a matter of when. There is not yet anyone working actively on it.

Comment: Please note that labels are typically meant as a 'classification', not a property itself.  When you label something you mean that "It's a ___", whereas properties (such as your FullName example) are more of the fields that describe the state of the ___.